# Fadein with variable as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to make a hover effect (make a div fadein, and then out when not hovering) on my list of pictures that users has uploadet. Since i dont want all my pictures to hover when one of the pictures are selected, i have made PHP echo out a variable for the divs ids.

In my jQuery code below, i got a loop where i count from 1 to 16 (thats the number of pictures in my gallery) and the selector has the name of the divs.

PHP Part:

```
                        echo "<div class='cell1' id=sovs$sovs style='overflow: hidden; position: relative;'>
                                <a href=image.php?p=$presentnew->upload_id>
                                <img style='min-width: 177px; min-height: 177px;' src='content/$presentnew->user_name/thumbs/medium_$presentnew->file_name'>
                                <div class='celltext'>
                                <b style='color: white; line-height: 28px; margin-left: 5px; font-size: 10pt;'><a style='color: white;' href='profil.php?bruger=$presentnew->user_name'>$presentnew->user_name</a></b>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>";
                        $sovs++;
                    }
```

Javascript Part:

```
for (var h = 1; h <= 16; h++) {
    $(function() {
        $("#sovs" + h).hover(

        function() {
            alert("g");
        });
    });
}​
```

The code above is just a test where i want my divs to respond to the function.

problem is that they dont do that. they will respond if i change the name of the selector to, for instance `$('#sovs1')`.

Can anybody enlighten me on what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(var h=1; h<=16; h++){   
        $("#sovs"+h).mouseover(function(){
                alert("G");                                  
            });   

    }
});
```

Works, but if i attach the fadeIn function to it, it doesn't

Comment: "this doesn't work at all" means what exactly? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net Or a full code!

Comment: I updated the post, maybe this makes it easier to understand

Comment: @MathiasFyrstJakobsen. Your update is impossible!

Comment: It looks like you need to use a `delegate event`.

Comment: Live,delegate or on ..jquery functions will do it for you :) check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give a lot more info to get an answer, just one important thing:

```
for (var h = 1; h <= 16; h++) {
    $(function() { // <======= This will create 16! dom ready event handlers
        $("#sovs" + h).hover(

        function() {
            alert("g");
        });
    });
}​
```

Move it to an outer scope (If needed at all..)

```
$(function() {
    for (var h = 1; h <= 16; h++) {
        $("#sovs" + h).hover(function() {
            alert("g");
        });
    }
}​
```

Try this code, to see if the problem is with delegate event VS direct event.

```
$(function() {
    for (var h = 1; h <= 16; h++) {
        $('body').on('mousemove', "#sovs" + h, function() {
            alert('g');
        });
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     for(var h=1; h<=16; h++) {   
        $("#sovs"+h).live('hover', function() {
                alert("g");                                         
        });   
    }
});
```

Comment: Should be noted it will not solve the problem. you can have (but shouldn't) multiple ready handlers.

Comment: This is great, and it works, although it alerts twice, dont know why? Also, if i change the alert to $("#celltext"+h).css("display","block") then it wont respond